# Chevrolet Cruze: Removed door cables. After attempt to start car it won't release key.

Tags: chevrolet, cruze

I had a issue with the window regulator on my Chevrolet Cruze. While I am 
attempting to fix it myself I tried to start the car and now I won't be able to take the key out. Not even a light is coming on when I turn the ignition.
What do I have to do to get the key back? I attached all the cables to the door 
but it makes no difference.

Comment: try to move the steering wheel as you try removing the key...sometimes if the steering wheel has pressure on it left or right pressure like having the wheels turned...will bind the steering wheel lock keeping the key feeling stuck....as far as the no lights check the battery connection..i hope you removed the neg battery cable before tried to fix ..if not try checking the fuses

Comment: Also ensure the vehicle is *completely* in park. Next door neighbor couldn't get her key out of the ignition. Turned out there was a small piece (radio button) which had fallen down in front of the floor shift lever. This wouldn't allow the shifter to go all the way forward into park (transmission would go into park, though). It was just enough to not allow the key to transition to the "off" position as though the transmission were still in gear.

Comment: Whats the year, trim and eighth vin character?